# Is this a reasonable way to test/compare javascript loop speeds?

Tags: javascript, array, benchmarking

I'm playing around with understanding array looping speed.
I'm trying to make the contenders equivalent and close to realistic.

- Is this a good approach?
- Are there other iteration approaches to test?

```js
let suite = new Benchmark.Suite();

const length = 10000;
const arrayToTest = [];
for (let i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
  arrayToTest.push({
    a: i,
    b: i / 2,
  });
}

const methods = {
  forForward: (array) => {
    const result = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
      const { a, b } = array[i];
      result.push(a + b);
    }

    return result;
  },

  forReverse: (array) => {
    const result = [];

    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i -= 1) {
      const { a, b } = array[i];
      result.push(a + b);
    }

    return result;
  },

  forOf: (array) => {
    const result = [];

    for (const { a, b } of array) {
      result.push(a + b);
    }

    return result;
  },

  forEach: (array) => {
    const result = [];

    array.forEach(({ a, b }) => {
      result.push(a + b);
    });

    return result;
  },

  map: (array) => {
    const result = array.map(({ a, b }) => a + b);

    return result;
  },

  reduce: (array) => {
    const result = array.reduce((acc, { a, b }) => {
      acc.push(a + b);

      return acc;
    }, []);

    return result;
  },
};


Object.entries(methods).forEach(([name, method]) => {
  suite = suite.add(name, () => method(arrayToTest));
});

suite
  .on('start', () => {
    console.log('Running speedtests...');
  })
  .on('cycle', (event) => {
    console.log(`  ${event.target}`);
  })
  .on('complete', function () {
    console.log(`\n ${this.filter('fastest').map('name')} is fastest.\n`);
  })
  .run({ async: false });
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/platform/1.3.5/platform.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/benchmark/2.1.4/benchmark.min.js"></script>
```

Here are some results with a local node install. I've run them over and over. These console log screenshots are representative of the common result.

When looking at relative performance, I don't understand why `map` and `reduce` vary so widely. `map` is very fast in the thousands, falls off, then makes a comeback when the iterations get higher.

I'm sure other engines will behave differently but I definitely find it curious. Ultimately I'd like to understand this stuff more but for now I'm really wondering if this is a fair comparison test.

### 100 iterations (And they're off! Everyone has a fast start)

[image: 100]

### 1,000 iterations (map takes the lead, reduce blows a tire)

[image: 1000]

### 10,000 iterations (map scrapes the wall and is momentarily stunned)

[image: 10000]

### 100,000 iterations (the race continues)

[image: 100000]

### 1,000,000 iterations (map makes a comeback)

[image: 10000000]

Comment: One issue is that this isn't a fair comparison, especially the array methods. `map` is used to transform one array to another. `reduce` is for reducing an array to one value. Sure, there are other array methods that "iterate" (filter, find, findIndex, etc.), but that's not their purpose. Using them to just iterate is like using a hammer to drive a screw. Also, implementation and performance vary by engine. If you're to compare "iteration" only, then only `forEach` is a viable competitor.

Comment: @Joseph Thanks for commenting. Your thoughts were exactly my thinking before starting this journey. But, for example, if `map` is always faster (in the javascript engine being used) and speed is the most important factor does it matter if it's meant for a given purpose?  Also, how is `forEach` is a viable competitor when it places at the bottom in every single race?

Comment: Because that's what `forEach` is for, iterating an array of items. The other methods aren't for that purpose, regardless of whether they're faster or not. There's more to code than just speed. Speed makes no sense if a developer ends up spinning their wheels trying to understand why some code was written in a weird way. Also, if were talking about going over an array items, _recursion_ is a glaring omission.

Comment: All points well taken. Thanks again. 
The genesis of this question is from a place in our code-base where speed matters more than readability. If no one else chimes in here we'll just move forward with what works in our situation. Not hard to change the code later.

Answer (score 1):

### The real world

You can test one style against another and learn nothing about which is the more performant.

Benchmarking JS code only has meaning when you are testing an actual real world example.

Why, because even the smallest seemingly inconsequential change can effect performance. Things like using a `const` or a literal, a `var` or a `let`, a zero `0.0` or a zero `0`, implied `!val` or explicit `val === 0`

Worse still, the next browser update can invalidate all the results of previous tests. Yesterday what was the fastest is now the slowest.

To your question.

### Apples and oranges

> *"Is this a good approach?"*

No!

Why. Because you are not testing loops, you are testing accessors. There is a difference in how destructure assignments work and rest parameters work.

Variables and parameters differ and accessing them by performing operations on them are effected by how they are declared and assigned.

One must also consider optimizations. Using array map lets the JS know the size of the array and thus eliminates the need to grow the array as items are added. Arrays grow by doubling in size as needed. These memory allocations as the array grows have a significant overhead, more so for small arrays than large.

### What are you testing

> *"Are there other iteration approaches to test?"*

The question I ask is what are you testing. Going by the question's title `loop speeds?` but going by the code you are testing array copy

Yes there are alternative tests but first lets change the test.

**Note** I did not use recursive solutions in any tests below because they are SO.. slow. Recursive function use the call stack and push the current function context to that stack each recursion. This is a huge overhead that is not worth benchmarking.

### Array copy

We simplify the input array to an array of numbers, and the operation is to create a copy.

**Note** that results of the copy are used to change a global `soak`. This ensures that the optimizer does not just ignore the function call (Some browser versions do not call functions if they do not change some external state)

Each method is directed through the function `call`

```js
const LENGTH = 1000;
const data = new Array(LENGTH).fill(0).map((a,i) => i);
var soak = 0;
function call(a, f) { soak += f(a)[Math.random() * LENGTH | 0] }
const methods = {
  for(array) {
const result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) { result.push(array[i]) }
return result;
  },
  forOf(array) {
const result = [];
for (const a of array) { result.push(a) }
return result;
  },
  forEach(array){
const result = [];
array.forEach(a => result.push(a));
return result;
  },
  map(array){ return  array.map(a => a) },
  filter(array) { return array.filter(() => true) },
  spread(array) { return [...array] },
};
```

For 1,000 items

| Name | Mean time | Max diff | Call per sec | Rel performance | Total time | Calls |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| spread | 0.889µs | ±0.886µs | 1,124,885 | 100.00% | 653ms | 735,000 |
| map | 5.822µs | ±1.571µs | 171,770 | 15.27% | 3,912ms | 672,000 |
| filter | 7.890µs | ±1.729µs | 126,740 | 11.27% | 5,854ms | 742,000 |
| forEach | 8.497µs | ±1.800µs | 117,686 | 10.46% | 5,710ms | 672,000 |
| for | 8.521µs | ±1.829µs | 117,353 | 10.43% | 6,502ms | 763,000 |
| forOf | 8.582µs | ±1.886µs | 116,523 | 10.36% | 5,287ms | 616,000 |

For 100,000 items

| Name | Mean time | Max diff | Call per sec | Rel performance | Total time | Calls |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| spread | 232.411µs | ±108.000µs | 4,302 | 100.00% | 848ms | 3,650 |
| forOf | 1,296.364µs | ±874.000µs | 771 | 17.92% | 6,417ms | 4,950 |
| for | 1,331.203µs | ±770.000µs | 751 | 17.46% | 8,520ms | 6,400 |
| forEach | 2,731.455µs | ±3,096.000µs | 366 | 8.51% | 13,521ms | 4,950 |
| map | 3,465.654µs | ±2,018.000µs | 288 | 6.69% | 18,021ms | 5,200 |
| filter | 4,622.660µs | ±1,122.000µs | 216 | 5.02% | 22,420ms | 4,850 |

To copy an array the spread operator is an order of magnitude faster than any alternative.

**Note** that `Array.from(array)` is identical to `[...array]`

### Iterating

This time lets test the performance of iterators

The setup

```js
const LENGTH = 1000;
const data = [
new Array(LENGTH).fill(0).map(() => Math.random()),
new Array(LENGTH).fill(0).map(() => Math.random()),
];

var soak = 0;
function call(a, f) { soak += f(a[Math.random() * 2 | 0]) }
const methods = {
forLet(array) {
    var v = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i ++) { v += array[i] }
    return v;
},
forVar(array) {
    var v = 0, i = 0;
    for (; i < array.length; i ++) { v += array[i] }
    return v;
},
forOf(array) {
    var v = 0;
    for (const a of array) { v += a }
    return v;
},
while(array) {
    var v = 0, i = array.length;
    while (i-- > 0) { v += array[i] }
    return v;
},
forEach(array){
    var v = 0;
    array.forEach(a => v += a);
    return v;
},
reducer(array){ 
    return array.reduce((v, a) => v + a, 0)
},
};
```

For 1,000 items.

| Name | Mean time | Max diff | Call per sec | Rel performance | Total time | Calls |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| forEach | 1.764µs | ±2.167µs | 566,771 | 100.00% | 540ms | 306,000 |
| forVar | 1.807µs | ±3.300µs | 553,311 | 97.63% | 569ms | 315,000 |
| reducer | 1.833µs | ±3.067µs | 545,454 | 96.24% | 567ms | 309,000 |
| forLet | 1.855µs | ±3.167µs | 539,207 | 95.14% | 568ms | 306,000 |
| while | 2.248µs | ±3.200µs | 444,935 | 78.50% | 634ms | 282,000 |
| forOf | 8.405µs | ±4.967µs | 118,972 | 20.99% | 2,370ms | 282,000 |

**Note** The order (performance) does not change as the size of the arrays grow in tens above 1000 items.

**Note** that in this case `reducer` is reasonably competitive.

### Tiny changes

What does this teach us. Nothing really, let make a small change and force one array to be integers.

```js
const LENGTH = 1000;
const data = [
new Array(LENGTH).fill(0).map(() => Math.random()),
new Array(LENGTH).fill(0).map(() => Math.random() * 100 | 0),
];

var soak = 0;
function call(a, f) { soak += f(a) }
const methods = {
forVar(array) {
    var v = 0, i = 0;
    array = array[1];
    for (; i < array.length; i ++) { v += array[i] }
    return v;
},
forLet(array) {
    var v = 0;
    array = array[0];
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i ++) { v += array[i] }
    return v;
},
reducer(array){ 
    return array[1].reduce((v, a) => v + a, 0)
},
};
```

Now I can select which array to process as I iterate. I want `forVar` to be the fastest so it will use the second array the others will use the first.

| Name | Mean time | Max diff | Call per sec | Rel performance | Total time | Calls |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| forVar | 1.261µs | ±0.460µs | 793,147 | 100.00% | 630ms | 500,000 |
| forLet | 1.647µs | ±0.560µs | 607,241 | 76.56% | 873ms | 530,000 |
| reducer | 1.833µs | ±0.560µs | 545,560 | 68.78% | 862ms | 470,000 |

Ok you can say the advantage is given to `forVar` integer math is always faster.

Is it?? Look at the code again. `reducer` is also using the second array yet it has gained no advantage.

<sub>**NOTE** All test on Chrome 92 (64bit) Win10 Laptop passive cooling.</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much for your time @Blindman67. This was enlightening. One thing I've leaned is for codereview the questions should be more specific rather than the more generic wording on stackoverflow. In the real world I'm iterating on arrays of object with varying lengths between 1000-10000. Sometimes I'm adding a key or updating a value, or copying/combining. The example arrays in my code sample were to mimic that a little. Then I picked on of the things I do often "combining" and did it similarly for each function. All your points about array copy are well taken, thanks.

Comment: As for iteration, I see now that as long as the cleaner (or more more used approach in the codebase) is best as long as it isn't a complete dog. i.e. - don't use forOf but the others are all fine. I've also found, even though Nodejs uses the V8 engine it doesn't perform the same as Chrome or Firefox and I'm sure the results will be even more different on iOS and Android javascript engines (our apps are React Native) so at the end of the day using better data structures and better Big O approaches will lead to bigger gains. I like the idea of benchmarking but see it's limited benefits now.